# How to change directory

Tags: command-line, directory, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cd-command

When I try to change my working directory to C:\Users\Michell Payano\Desktop\Data Analytics Tools, the result is `-bash: cd: too many arguments`. I want to know what is wrong.

Comment: It's not clear what command you are using the change the directory.  It would help if you provided the specific line of code.  However, there may be at least two issues - (1) Linux doesn't use drive designators like C: (check the mount point for this disk partition), and (2) folder names that contain spaces must be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate to C drive in bash on WSL-Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943006/how-to-navigate-to-c-drive-in-bash-on-wsl-ubuntu)

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/398400/how-do-i-navigate-to-folders-with-spaces-in-their-names-i-get-no-such-file-or

Answer (score 5):

The problem is the spaces between Michell and Payano, between Data and Analytics, and between Analytics and Tools.

Use this:

```
cd "C:\Users\Michell Payano\Desktop\Data Analytics Tools"
```

or this:

```
cd C:\\Users\\Michell\ Payano\\Desktop\\Data\ Analytics\ Tools
```

In the first form, the whole path is put in double quotes to avoid the string from being broken up. In the second form, spaces are "escaped" by preceding them with a backslash, meaning that they are part of the path. The backslashes already in the path need to be escaped as well to be recognized as path separators.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, thanks, I missed the first space. Will edit. Didn't elaborate about escaping the backslashes because I'm not sure how WSL (where this comes from, presumably) handles these.